# "conda install -c conda-forge python" causes anaconda distribution to stop working

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried running `conda install -c conda-forge python`. The installed python package causes Anaconda python to stop working. When I type `python` on the console, nothing happens. Did anyone encounter the same problem? Any fixes?

The latest python version v3.9.13 from conda-forge channel will break the anaconda package, at least on my PC. I don't know if anyone else faces the same problem.

I am using Windows 10. I am running Anaconda 2022.05.

*Update: I no longer face any problem with python v3.9.13 from conda-forge channel. I do not even have to run the solution provided in the answer. Maybe the Anaconda team did something to fix the problem I faced.*

Comment: Did you run the installation in a conda environment?

Comment: I ran it on a console as Admin.

Comment: So you didn't create an environment with conda, then installed Python in that environment? Just to double check, so I don't give incorrect suggestions.

Comment: Don't really understand your comment. I'm running Anaconda distribution. Isn't that a conda environment? Do you mean a virtual environment? I did not set up a virtual env.

Comment: A *Conda* environment. That is usually the best for a new project (i.e., one environment per project). That way, you can install the precise versions of dependencies  for each project, including newer/older Python versions. Since Anaconda itself depends on Python, installing another Python version in the base environment can (as you experience) mess up Anaconda.

Comment: More information is at https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-environments . It may be worth reading the full user's guide to Conda. Note that Anaconda is a distribution with many packages built around the Conda tool, so you can use Conda and its documentation fine.

Comment: As for the problem at hand: backup any code you already have, then see if you can uninstall Anaconda. That may not work if it's broken, but the uninstaller may still work. If or if not that works, try and re-install a fresh Anaconda; hopefully it will install over any remaining Anaconda installation, fixing the broken version along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** You need to activate the environment with `conda activate base` to use it in the command prompt in windows. (check below for more details, including virtual env)

### Explaination

Even though you have installed python with `conda install -c conda-forge python`, this probably happened to your base environment, which is still inaccessible because you need to do `conda activate base` (in Linux OS `conda source base`). This is done to run python successfully outside the **anaconda prompt** (you seem to be using **cmd with admin privileges**).

Also like others mentioned in the comments, conda is usually used to make isolated environments for each application. [As seen per the documentation, and below](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html):

`conda create -n <env_name>`

`conda activate <env_name>`

`conda install -c conda_forge python` (This can be combined into the first line, by adding python after <env_name>, even with a specific version like `python=3.8`)